# Validation of time and updating another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
df['r_time'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['createTimestamp']).time
df1 = df[df['Region'].str.contains('to be updated')]

for ind in df1.index:
    if df1['r_time'] < '8:00:00':
        df1['Region'] = 'Americas'
```

ending with below error

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two masks, not that you cannot compare directly a time to a string, you need to use [`pd.Timestamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html):

```
# is the region to be updated?
m1 = df['Region'].str.contains('to be updated')
# is the time before 8:00:00?
m2 = (pd.to_datetime(df['createTimestamp']).dt.time
        .lt(pd.Timestamp('8:00:00').time())
     )

# update
df.loc[m1&m2, 'Region'] = 'Americas'
```

Comment: It worked as expected, but need some suggestion to improvise the code. Where we have multiple condition like 
Between 00:00:01 to 08:00:00 then "Americas"
Between 08:00:01 to 16:00:00 then "Europe"
Between 16:00:01 to 23:59:59 then "APAC"

Answer (score 1):

You can create time column by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), then instead comapre with string `8:00:00` convert it to `time`s and set new values to column with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and chained both mask by `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
times = pd.to_datetime(df['createTimestamp']).dt.time 

m1 = times < pd.to_datetime('8:00:00').time()

m2 = df['Region'].str.contains('to be updated')

df.loc[m1 & m2, 'Region'] = 'Americas'
```